# Find Value Of Variable At Specific Iteration of For Loop

Tags: c#

I know this is probably a rudimentary question, however I am new to c#. Lets say I have the following for loop:

```
        int foo;
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            foo = i+10;
        }
```

How can I find the value of foo at say, i=4. Also, how can I find the vale of foo at say, the previous run of the for loop?

Comment: You should add the values into a collection (array or List) if you want to use all/any of the values after your loop is done. Or, if you need the values as you are processing them, just pass them into a method, or do the processing inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to do this:

```
    int loopStop = 5;
    int[] foo = new int[loopStop -1];
    for (int i = 1; i < loopStop; i++)
    {
        foo[i -1] = i+10;  //arrays are 0 based in C#.
    }

    Console.WriteLine(foo[3]); //shows for position 4 in the array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some things you can add to your program to do what you were asking.

```
int foo;
int previousValue;
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    //how can I find the value the previous run of the for loop?
    previousValue = foo; 
    foo = i+10;
    //How can I find the value of foo at say, i=4. 
    if (i == 4)
    {
        // Do whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of the loop iterator in c# is not valid outside the for loop.  Doing for loop like code below will solve issue.  The Developers of c language K & R often used this technique in their book "The C Language".  The final value of i will equal 5.

```
            int foo;
            int i = 1;
            for (; i < 5; i++)
            {
                foo = i + 10;
            }​
```